# weka sparse arff file

Tags: weka, sparse-matrix, arff

I am making a sparse arff file but it will not load into Weka. I get the error that I have the wrong number of values in the @attribute class line, it expects 1 and rejects receiving 12. What am I doing wrong? My file looks like this:

```
%ARFF file for questions data
%

@relation brazilquestions

@attribute att0 numeric
@attribute att1 numeric
@attribute att2 numeric
@attribute att3 numeric
%there are 469 attributes which represent my bag of words
@attribute class {Odontologia_coletiva, Periodontia, Pediatria, Estomatologia,   
Dentistica, Ortodontia, Endodontia, Cardiologia, Terapeutica, 
Terapeutica_medicamentosa, Odontopediatria, Cirurgia}


@data
{126 1, 147 1, 199 1, 56 1, 367 1, 400 1 , Estomatologia}
{155 1, 76 1, 126 1, 78 1, 341 1, 148 1, Odontopediatria}
%and then 81 more instances of data
```

Any ideas about what is wrong with my syntax? I followed the example exactly from the book Data Mining by Witten/Frank/Hall. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you write the error, please?

Comment: The error reads:
weka.core.converters.CSVLoaderfailed to load 'ARFF file for question data.txt'.
Reason:
wrong number of values. Read 12, expected 1, read Token[EOL], line 477.

Comment: Line 477 is empty, but Line 476 contains the line with @attribute class

Comment: Have you tried to put a @data with 7 attributes??

Comment: The data represents questions, all the questions have different values associated with them since each question has different words (those are the attributes) and word frequencies. So the data is actually (word1 frequency, word2 frequency, ..., classification of the question)

Answer (score 1):

the problem in data section .
you must put the index of the class attribute

for example :

{126 1, 147 1, 199 1, 56 1, 367 1, 400 1 , Estomatologia}

correct it like the following

{126 1, 147 1, 199 1, 56 1, 367 1, 400 1 ,470 Estomatologia}

Answer (score 0):

In your document you declared 5 attributes but in @data you are adding 7 attributes, then  you should to complete the rest of values in @data. [You can see this in the manual](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html)

Comment: I have 469 words in my attribute list because that is the total number of words in my bag of words. My file is supposed to be of the sparse variety.

Comment: But you need to complete te attributes that you are not to use with 0 in the @data

Comment: The list is complete, I didn't include the whole list for brevity, I noted this with  "  %there are 469 attributes which represent my bag of words  " in the original post. Would it help to see the entire file?

Comment: According to the manual: "Note that the omitted values in a sparse instance are 0, they are not "missing" values! If a value is unknown, you must explicitly represent it with a question mark (?)."

Answer (score 0):

The attribute name for the instance class value needs to be listed, too.  (See the [Sparse ARFF file description](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html).)

Your file:

```
@attribute myclass {Odontologia_coletiva, Periodontia, Pediatria, Estomatologia,   
Dentistica, Ortodontia, Endodontia, Cardiologia, Terapeutica, 
Terapeutica_medicamentosa, Odontopediatria, Cirurgia}

@data
{126 1, 147 1, 199 1, 56 1, 367 1, 400 1 , Estomatologia}
```

Should be:

```
@data
{126 1, 147 1, 199 1, 56 1, 367 1, 400 1 , myclass Estomatologia}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ATTRIBUTE class string
```

Try using this instead of

```
@attribute class {Odontologia_coletiva, Periodontia, Pediatria, Estomatologia,  Dentistica, Ortodontia, Endodontia, Cardiologia, Terapeutica, Terapeutica_medicamentosa, Odontopediatria, Cirurgia}
```